# Populating a ListView in a Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments, listadapter

I'm new to android and I have searched through a lot of answer but none of them worked for me.

May base application is android Navigation Drawer example in which there are two fragments, one for the menu drawer and the other for the content.
What I want to do is that when I open the drawer and click on an item (title of a catagory) then I can retrieve data from SQLite database and show the list of items in ListView.

this is the method that sets the content of the content fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chapter, container, false);
    int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_CATEGORY_NUMBER);
    String chapter = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category)[i];

    // int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(chapter.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
    // "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
    //دو خط بالا برای انتخاب عکس های مختلف بود، من غیر فعال کردم

    ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(R.drawable.map_various);

    //اضافه شده توسط من تا کامنت بعدی

    TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
    tv.setText("some text");
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.commandText);
    tv2.setText("other price text");

    ListView lv= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), lessons);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    //تا اینجا توسط من اضافه شده بود


    getActivity().setTitle(chapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

And this is my list adapter.

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Lesson> {
    Context context;
    List<Lesson> lessons;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, List<Lesson> lessons) {
        super(context, android.R.id.content, lessons);
        this.context = context;
        this.lessons = lessons;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        View view = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem_lesson, null);

        Lesson lesson = lessons.get(position);

        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        tv.setText(lesson.getTitle());

        tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.commandText);
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(lesson.getCommand()));

        return view;
    }
}
```

My application doesn't open at all.
How can I use a list adapter inside a method of and activity by using a list Adapter to show content of a list view inside a fragment?

Comment: IF your app is crashing, post the error or stack trace that Logcat is giving to you. I'm guessing you're getting a Null Pointer Error in onCreateView(). Try keeping code out of onCreateView and move code into onStart(). I can't give a better suggestion unless you post the error

Comment: may be this line  ListView lv= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView); should be like this if the listview is on fragment  ListView lv= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);